# Gnome Shell: Unable to log into Xorg directly, yet Gnome Classic lets me log in

Tags: nvidia, gnome, xorg, gdm

--Edit for Clarification--

I'm unable to login to the Xorg version of Gnome, but I'm still able to access it with the "Gnome Classic" shell extension from GDM. I'm wondering if anyone has encountered this problem and could point me in the direction of the correct file or directory that would be most relevant to getting Xorg to log in.

I'm having an issue with GDM3 when I attempt to log into Gnome on Xorg in order to enable the Nvidia GPU with which to game. I use Nvidia-Prime to switch between Intel and Nvidia. I use the Ubuntu kernel on Xorg for gaming and the latest working mainline or stable for daily activities on Wayland. The oddity is that I can not access the Gnome Shell under Xorg, yet can log into Classic and Wayland perfectly and this occurs under Intel and Nvidia on all installed Kernels.

This is mainly an irritation as I can still game to my heart's content, but I'm attempting to discover the root cause if anyone knows the answer. This is my first question on this site, so I apologize if I've left anything out.

**Attempted Mitigation**

- Switch to various kernels to determine if anything changes.
- Purge Nvidia modules and reinstalled drivers and rebuilt kernel with new drivers and configuration files.
- Attempted to log into each session under Nvidia and Intel GPUs. No dice with Xorg under either GPU.
- Run Startx from console and check logs. Fail whale shows up with Xorg.
- PPA-purge of Padoka PPA
- Add new user to see if the problem is based on my existing user profile. No Dice.

**What I'm Considering**

I'm really hoping I'm just an idiot and it's something small, but...

- Purge of Gnome-Shell*
- Purge of Xserver/Xorg

**Specifications:**

- System76 Oryx Pro (oryp3)
- Ubuntu 17.10 with Gnome 3.26.2
- Kernels: 4.15rc6 - 4.13.0.21.24 - 4.13.0.21.22
- CPU: i7-7700HQ
- GPU(s)

  - Intel 591b
  - Nvidia GP106M (GTX1060 Mobile) Nvidia-Prime with 387.34
- Graphics:

  - Xorg 1.19.5
  - OpenGL Renderer: Intel HD Graphics 630
  - 4.5 Mesa 17.4.0-devel - Padoka PPA

Comment: Could you state that as a question?

Comment: My apologies, I'll edit to reflect as well. I'm unable to login to the Xorg version of Gnome, but I'm still able to access it with the "Gnome Classic" shell extension from GDM. I'm wondering if anyone has encountered this problem and could point me in the direction of the correct file or directory that would be most relevant to getting Xorg to log in.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused in part by removing "ubuntu-session" from GDM. It still does not explain the reason that Gnome-Classic will allow logins, yet Xorg will not.

By reinstalling ubuntu-session, the issue was resolved.